# Inter Process (from different users) Communication in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Which is best way for inter process(from different users) communication in objective c?
Can we use Open MPI in cocoa application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "best" method for inter-process communication in Cocoa is the one most suitable for your needs.

If you just need to send simple notifications, check out [`NSDistributedNotifcationCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you need to send more data, check out [`NSConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [`NSPipe`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPipe_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

OpenMPI also seems like a good choice, see [this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/274400-openmpi-in-xcode-3-2.html) about using it with Xcode.

If you have any questions, feel free to comment.

Comment: can we use above methods for communication between processes from different users?

Comment: @Catfish_Man I am using distributed object for Inter Process Communication.I want to implement two way communication between 4-5 processes. How one process find resister connection name of other process?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to spudwaffle's suggestions, the new hotness is XPC (requires Lion). For lightweight notifications, notify_post() is pretty awesome.

Comment: Hi @Catfish_Man! Are you able to provide any links to notify_post() examples? Google isn't giving much love.