# What Objective-C IPC mechanism to use?

Tags: objective-c, ipc, nsnotifications, distributed-objects

I have an application that maintains a group of nested objects, of custom classes.  This application needs to be able to share it's data, as it changes, with multiple Quartz Composer compositions with very similar custom Provider Patches.  The QC compositions are run inside this application.

QC patches can only handle limited object types on their inputs, so it doesn't seem like my custom classes will work there.  I'm also hesitant to hardwire the compositions to my application in such a way that would require me to add new Objective-C code very time I add a new composition.

I've tried Distributed Objects, even though I was warned against them.  I found them to be too unreliable.  As my QC patches are running at 60fps, they are attempting to access the vended object so frequently that I can't gracefully shut down the connection upon a failure, before it crashes.

Right now, I'm using Distributed Notifications to send dictionaries of updates to my QC patches every time something changes which is roughly ever second.  I serialize my custom classes into dictionaries so that I can do this, and then un-serialize the dictionaries in each of up to 5 instances of patches that receive this data.  This works, but it seems inefficient, and I'm concerned about the warnings of potential delayed and dropped messages.  My patches need to receive the updates in a very timely manner (less than .1 second, and faster is better), and with no drops.

What is the best mechanism for me to use to get the data from my application to my custom QC patches?

Thank you!
Adam

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661923/inter-process-from-different-users-communication-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be high level, XPC is the way to go (and it even got a nice update to use it with Objective-C directly in Mountain Lion (take a look into the `NSXPC` prefixed classes and protocols)). If this turns out to be too slow (it shouldn't because XPC is very leightweight), you can try to fall back to mach messages, the thing that virtually every kind of IPC uses on OS X. But! mach messages generation through MIG is a pain in the ass, so you should try XPC first and only if it turns out to be too slow, try mach messages.

And overview on how to create XPC services can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html)